# How do I best set up a repository for an Android app?

Tags: android, eclipse, repository

I am setting up a repository on Github for the source code of my Android app. I am using Eclipse with the ADT plugin. Besides everything in src/, res/, and AndroidManifest.xml, what else should I include so that anyone who wants to work with the source code can begin work with Eclipse with minimal effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should include everything except the `bin`-folder (this can be generated by the other user). Also, if you're using Eclipse, you might want to use [eGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/).

Comment: Oh didn't know about eGit. That's great!

Comment: eGit looks nice. But also, should I include gen/ folder (the one with R.java)?

Comment: Normally, this can be generated by the user, too. But I found that this sometimes causes problems when trying to build the project. So yes, I would include it.

Answer (score 1):

Set up the repository (git init) on the root of the directory and you will avoid thinking on such problems. Just add the changes that git status shows every time you wish to update the repository and push. 
Anyway try not to include the .class files - i.e its useless as the contributors can compile the code theirselves.

Basically:

```
cd yourproject
git init
git add . (or git status to check before what to add)
git commit -m 'this is an example of a commit'
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/yourprojectnameingithub.git
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also include your lib directory (that includes .jar files) if you have one.